# UIButton overlapping and hidden unexpectedly inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have created a`UIButton` programmatically inside the custom`UITableViewCell`, No. of`UIButtons` inside the cell is dynamic and at first it looks working perfect but when I open all the collapsed cell and scroll the table view `UIButton` overlap each other and If I scroll more the the `UIButton` in view outside the screen become hidden when thy come back to screen area here is  image what it looks like.

I am not posting code here because its big and I don't know which part should I include here. If asked  I will post that particular code here.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    InterestTableViewCell *cell = (InterestTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *category= (NSString *)[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSMutableArray *subcat =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *keys = [cat allKeys];
    id aKey = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    subcat = [cat objectForKey:aKey];
    cell.btnGroupTap.tag = indexPath.row+10000;
    NSArray *count=(NSArray *)subcat;
    int xoffset;
    int yoffset = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<count.count;i++)
    {
         if(i==0)
        {
            xoffset=0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(i%2 == 0)
            {
            xoffset = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                xoffset = 150;
            }
        }
        if(i==0)
        {
            yoffset = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                yoffset = yoffset+45;
            }
        }
        NSString *sel = subcat[i][@"selected"];
        NSString *key =subcat[i][@"key"];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        UIImage *image;
        if(![sel boolValue])
        {
            image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"unchecked.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"checked.png"];
        }
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(29,18,20,20)];
        [imageView setImage:image];
        UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [lbl1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,100,20)];
        lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        lbl1.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        lbl1.frame = CGRectMake(40,0,100,40);
        lbl1.numberOfLines =0;
        [lbl1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:12]];
        lbl1.text= subcat[i][@"value"];
        button.tag= [key integerValue];
        [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:normal];
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
        button.frame = CGRectMake(xoffset,20+yoffset,(screenWidth/2)-40,40);
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(CheckAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button addSubview:lbl1];
        [cell.ContainerView addSubview:button];
        [cell.ContainerView bringSubviewToFront:button];
    }
    cell.ContainerView.hidden=YES;
    cell.lblCategory.text = category;
    return cell;
}
```

[**Full Code at github**](https://github.com/varun-naharia/CategoryCheckBox)

**Note:** I used `[tableView beginUpdates];[tableView endUpdates];` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Please share the code for `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method

Comment: Please add `CheckAction:` event code

Comment: CheckAction Doesn't require because it we are not calling it anyway but if you want I will share that too

Comment: @VarunNaharia,  I have updated `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and posted in below answer, have you used the suggested changes?

Comment: As you are using reusable cells via dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: so if the cell is reused it will be already having the previously added CategoryView (basically subviews). You need to remove them first and than ass the new ones, you need to do it as

`for (UIView *subview in cell.ContainerView.subViews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [((UIButton *) subview) removeTarget:nil
                       action:NULL
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];  
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

The thing is you are using Reusable cells. Think of it as a shopping cart in the market. You will never know if it is new one, maybe you will get one with products already in it. You should always clean your cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and then proceed with your code.

**#edit**
Seems like cleaning your containerView should help. Like:

```
InterestTableViewCell *cell = (InterestTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
[[cell.ContainerView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: Since you are doing everything in collectionView in your cell, it should be fine with removing every subview from it.

Comment: it did work but not for hiding thing but for only overlapping

Comment: please comment something why is it hiding on scroll ? overlapping is corrected by your code but not hide on scroll

Comment: Move the code creating subviews to cell class, and use method prepareForReuse. Also check your autolayout since on your github it was a lot of bugs.

Comment: I exactly don't know right way to move the code to cell class should I just cut and paste the code of`cellForRowatIndexPath` ?

Comment: From `NSString *category..` to the line before return cell, usually should be in cell class. Then make a public property (.h file) with your data types. Long way to go, hard to explain everything in the comment section. Hope you got what you need to search for.

Comment: Do you Know any example code that do the same without looking at code it's hard to understand and search

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `reusable cells` via `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`: so if the cell is reused it will be already having the previously added `CategoryView` (basically `subviews`). You need to remove them first and than ass the new ones, you need to do it as

```
for (UIView *subview in cell.ContainerView.subViews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [((UIButton *) subview) removeTarget:nil
                       action:NULL
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];  
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Add above method inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: method as-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    InterestTableViewCell *cell = (InterestTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    for (UIView *subview in cell.ContainerView.subViews) {
     if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
          [((UIButton *) subview) removeTarget:nil
                                        action:NULL
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];  
          [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    NSString *category= (NSString *)[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSMutableArray *subcat =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSArray *keys = [cat allKeys];
        id aKey = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        subcat = [cat objectForKey:aKey];
        cell.btnGroupTap.tag = indexPath.row+10000;
        NSArray *count=(NSArray *)subcat;
        int xoffset;
        int yoffset = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<count.count;i++)
        {
             if(i==0)
            {
                xoffset=0;
            }
            else
            {
                if(i%2 == 0)
                {
                xoffset = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    xoffset = 150;
                }
            }
            if(i==0)
            {
                yoffset = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if(i%2==0)
                {
                    yoffset = yoffset+45;
                }
            }
            NSString *sel = subcat[i][@"selected"];
            NSString *key =subcat[i][@"key"];
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            UIImage *image;
            if(![sel boolValue])
            {
                image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"unchecked.png"];
            }
            else
            {
                image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"checked.png"];
            }
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(29,18,20,20)];
            [imageView setImage:image];
            UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            [lbl1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,100,20)];
            lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            lbl1.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            lbl1.frame = CGRectMake(40,0,100,40);
            lbl1.numberOfLines =0;
            [lbl1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:12]];
            lbl1.text= subcat[i][@"value"];
            button.tag= [key integerValue];
            [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:normal];
            CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
            button.frame = CGRectMake(xoffset,20+yoffset,(screenWidth/2)-40,40);
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(CheckAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [button addSubview:lbl1];
            [cell.ContainerView addSubview:button];
            [cell.ContainerView bringSubviewToFront:button];
        }
    cell.ContainerView.hidden=YES;
    cell.lblCategory.text = category;
    return cell;
}
```

**Note**: Also if you are using manual memory management scheme for memory management than you need to properly balance the retain count of your objects, for example after creating any `subview` and adding it fire a `release` message there. And finally remove it from superview if it's no longer required. I have added these `removeFromSuperView`/ `release` statements in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: method.

**But as you are using ARC than system will manage the retain /release calls on the object to manage memory**

Comment: i tried your code but it's not working don't know why

Comment: @VarunNaharia have you replaced the whole method or just the suggested changes?

Comment: @VarunNaharia I have updated my code, please use the updated one, it will work

Comment: error when try to add full code `'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic refernce continf mode` and `ARC forbids explicit message send 'release'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79642/discussion-between-sanjay-mohnani-and-varun-naharia).